# LINQ Extension method to find count of "Present"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, linq-to-entities

[LINQ: How to find the count of "Present" for Alex between 5-Jan-2020 to 10-Feb-2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBxcE.png)

How to find the count of "Present" for Alex between 5-Jan-2020 to 10-Feb-2020 using linq extension method

Image of table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBxcE.png

Comment: You need to show us some effort at least, give us some code, have you tried anything yet? This looks very lazy as it stands right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count of a collection using the Count() method.

Lets use your data as an example, you can use any filters and then use count() to get the count of the results:

```
var result = table.where( t => t.Month > fromDate && t.Month < toDate && Employee == "employeeName" && Attendance == "present").Count()
```

Result will then be an integer value with the count of the results